# flex datagrid sorting which contain itemrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, datagrid, itemrenderer

I'm quite newbies of flex,  may I have some question to anyone who can suggest please.

I have grid for monitor CPU status  and It look like this

CPU | CPU dif
--------------
5.9 |  +0.2 ^
4.0 |  -0.6 v
12.7|  -1.5 v

The `^ , v` in the picture above represent for `[s:itemrenderer]`

The problem is the column "CPU dif" cannot normally sort , so I use sortCompareFunction to solve this

```
public static function compareCPU(typeOne:Object, typeTwo:Object ,grid:Object):int
{
  return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(Number(typeOne.cpu), Number(typeTwo.cpu) );
}
public static function compareCPUdif(typeOne:Object, typeTwo:Object ,grid:Object):int
{
  return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(Number(typeOne.cpu_dif), Number(typeTwo.cpu_dif) );
}
```

AND

```
<s:GridColumn headerText="Cpu%" dataField="cpu" sortCompareFunction="compareCPU"/>
<s:GridColumn width="90" headerText="Cpu% Dif"  sortCompareFunction="compareCPUdif">
  <s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
      <s:GridItemRenderer width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="left">
          <s:HGroup width="50%" paddingLeft="5" horizontalAlign="left">
            <s:Label text="{data.cpu_dif}"/>
          </s:HGroup>    
          <s:HGroup  width="50%" paddingRight="5" horizontalAlign="right">
            <mx:Image source="{outerDocument.statusArrow.getItemAt(data.pic)as String}"/>
          </s:HGroup>
        </s:HGroup>
      </s:GridItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```

It looks strange that it's works for a half , they can sort correctly only one way (Ascending-sort)
When i have clicked it again, there is no responding.

Could you have any solution for this issue?
Highest thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Shigeky have you a solution for this problem?..because maybe I have one. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably treat the '+' and '-' characters as .. well. characters and not math symbols.

Take the objects that the sort provides you, convert them to numbers on your own and THEN apply the `numericCompare`.